Is there a way to get the content from Azure Document Intelligence in markdown BUT separated page by page?
This is what I tried. Content is in markdown but I don't have the page by page separation. On the other hand if I go into the pages attribute, there is no markdown.
document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))
poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
    "prebuilt-layout",
    analyze_request=AnalyzeDocumentRequest(base64_source=doc_bytes),
    output_content_format=ContentFormat.MARKDOWN
)

As mentioned above. I also tried with the "pages" attribute -
document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key))
poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document(
    "prebuilt-layout",
    analyze_request=AnalyzeDocumentRequest(base64_source=doc_bytes),
    output_content_format=ContentFormat.MARKDOWN,
    pages='1'
)

and iterate through the doc, but even though it's one page it still takes as much time to analyze as the full document.

Does the Split option help?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/ai-document-intelligence-rest-readme?view=azure-node-preview#split-options

Leveraging Azure Document Intelligence Layout API with markdown output will provide all content in a single response by default. You can split the markdown content per page, by looking at the page information (span offset and length) provided in the response.
See below code example (Python) which can be used to split the markdown content:
# Split markdown content per page
content_per_page = []
page_number = 1

for page in result.pages: 
    content = result.content[page.spans[0]['offset']: page.spans[0]['offset'] + page.spans[0]['length']]
    content_per_page.append({"page_number": page_number, "content": content})
    page_number+=1


This gave me exactly what I needed. It kept the markdown uneffected, while still allowing me to split by page number. The other method (using result.pages.lines) ends up changing the markdown.

using Azure Document Intelligence to extract content from documents and would like to separate the content page by page:

Followed this Azure AI Document Intelligence client  with python

for page in result.pages:
    # Create a string to hold the Markdown content for this page
    markdown_content = ""
    
    # Iterate through each element on the page
    for element in page.lines:
        # Append each line to the markdown_content string
        markdown_content += f"{element.content}\n"
    
    # Append the markdown content to the markdown_pages list
    markdown_pages.append(markdown_content)


The below Python code extract content from documents and separates the content page by page
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential

# Set up the client
endpoint ="https://your-service-endpoint.cognitiveservices.azure.com/"
api_key = "your-api-key"
client = DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(api_key))

# Analyze the document
document_url = "https://sampath1233sa23344545.blob.core.windows.net/sampathpujari/sample-layout_merged%20(1).pdf?sp=r&st=2024-04-17T11:50:23Z&se=2024-04-17T19:50:23Z&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=r6USzR4zcaECjsNw9HAbJ%2BvzRwrk3InrBmaXklxbs5c%3D"

# Begin document analysis
analysis_poller = client.begin_analyze_document_from_url("prebuilt-document", document_url)
result = analysis_poller.result()  # Wait for the analysis to complete and get the result

# Initialize a list to hold the markdown content for each page
markdown_pages = []

# Iterate through each page
for page in result.pages:
    # Create a string to hold the Markdown content for this page
    markdown_content = ""
    
    # Iterate through each element on the page
    for element in page.lines:
        # Append each line to the markdown_content string
        markdown_content += f"{element.content}\n"
    
    # Append the markdown content to the markdown_pages list
    markdown_pages.append(markdown_content)

# The markdown_pages list now contains the content of each page in Markdown format
for i, content in enumerate(markdown_pages):
    print(f"Page {i + 1}:\n{content}\n")



Output:



Refer to this for  Analyze complex documents with Azure Document Intelligence Markdown Output


Thanks for the comment! With this approach, I am losing my table markdown formatting which is important to preserve. :(

Refer to link for Markdown representation of the extracted table

Thanks, I went through it from the answer link already. I know I can get this sort of output of the table and that's why I went with a markdown format initially. Problem with this approach is that I lose the page separation, and if I try to iterate through content.pages and then .lines, I lose the markdown structure.


I Use  table example in this doc

